# My calculations aren't working in jscript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript coding and I know enough to structure a function/arguement, but not enough to troubleshoot.

Here's the portion of my code in question. I'm trying to yield a rounded integer value from a series of calculations, but I can't seem to get it to work.

If this worked correctly, it would grab the 20000 value, multiply it by 3 [60000], then divide that by 3250 [18.4615...], then round down to the nearest number [18]. Then it rewrites the text in the browser to 18.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var moneyInSeats = $('#moneyInSeats');
  var moneyInSeatsValue = moneyInSeats;
  var moneyMultiplier = 3;

  if (moneyInSeatsValue.text() != '') {
    var seatsVisible = ((moneyInSeatsValue.text()) * moneyMultiplier);
    var seatsPerSection = 3250;
    var sectionsVisibleExact = seatsVisible / seatsPerSection;
    var sectionsVisibleRounded = Math.floor(sectionsVisibleExact);

    moneyInSeats.text(moneyMultiplier);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="moneyInSeats" class="hotField">20000</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code/calculation is fine, you were printing wrong value to the UI (`moneyInSeats`)

```
    moneyInSeats.text(sectionsVisibleRounded)
```

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="moneyInSeats" class="hotField">20000</p>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var moneyInSeats = $('#moneyInSeats');
      var moneyInSeatsValue = moneyInSeats
      var moneyMultiplier = 3;

      if (moneyInSeatsValue.text() != '') {
        var seatsVisible = ((moneyInSeatsValue.text()) *
          moneyMultiplier);
        var seatsPerSection = 3250;
        var sectionsVisibleExact = seatsVisible / seatsPerSection;
        var sectionsVisibleRounded =
          Math.floor(sectionsVisibleExact)

        moneyInSeats.text(sectionsVisibleRounded)

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't convert the value from `moneyInSeatsValue.text()` into a number.

Use this:

`parseInt(moneyInSeatsValue.text(),10)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var moneyInSeats = $('#moneyInSeats');
  var moneyInSeatsValue = moneyInSeats;
  var moneyMultiplier = 3;

  if (moneyInSeatsValue.text() != '') {
    var str = "moneyMultiplier: "+moneyMultiplier+'<br>';
    var seatsVisible = (parseInt(moneyInSeatsValue.text(),10) * moneyMultiplier);
    str += 'seatsVisible: '+seatsVisible+'<br>';
    var seatsPerSection = 3250;
    str += 'seatsPerSection: '+seatsPerSection+'<br>';
    var sectionsVisibleExact = seatsVisible / seatsPerSection;
    str += 'sectionsVisibleExact: '+sectionsVisibleExact+'<br>';
    var sectionsVisibleRounded = Math.floor(sectionsVisibleExact);
    str += 'sectionsVisibleRounded: '+sectionsVisibleRounded+'<br>';

    moneyInSeats.html(str);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="moneyInSeats" class="hotField">20000</p>
```